# Use a condition in filter function

Tags: r, dplyr

In an R function using {dplyr}, I would like to use a condition within a filter functionn like this :

I got this issue :
`Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) :  Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector`

```
myfunction <- function(param="one") {

  iris %>% 
    filter(
      if (param=="one") {
        #do nothing
      } else if (param=="two") {Species=="setosa"})
  
}

myfunction(param="one")
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I find it weird to use `if` condition inside `dplyr::filter`.

Comment: You might try `dplyr::mutate` or  `dplyr::ifelse` function

Comment: I don't want to add a column but just want to filter a data frame with a condition in my function. In my example, if param=="one" do not filter iris and if param=="two" filter with my condition

Answer (score 0):

Make the two conditions as a combined or logical statement. My understanding of what you're trying to do is get the rows where either `param == 'one'` or `param == 'two' and Species == 'setosa'`

With that you can you the following filter

```
# sample data and package
data(iris)
library(tidyverse)
# make a random param column
new_df = iris %>% mutate(param = sample(c('one','two','three'),
                                        size=nrow(.),
                                        replace=T))

# Conduct filter
filtered_df = new_df %>%
  filter((param == 'one') | (param == 'two' & Species == 'setosa'))
```

Comment: Thanks but I just want to filter a data frame with a condition in my function. In my example, if param=="one" do not filter iris and if param=="two" filter with my condition

Answer (score 0):

In this simple case I would do it like this:

```r
myfunction <- function(param="one") {
  out <- iris
  if (param != "one")
    out <- out %>% filter(Species == "setosa")
  return(out)
}
```